# Contact Form Validation Issues

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my contact form to validate and show what is required to the user but i've been having issues getting all of the inputs to behave.

You can see it here: http://denverbarr.com

For some reason the placeholders aren't behaving correctly in that they have a weird padding that was not set. And for some reason I can't get the name input to validate.

Here is the code I've been using:

**HTML CODE**

```
    <div class="six col text-center" id="contact">

                                            <div id="contactform">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                      <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <input placeholder="Name" id="user_name" name="user_name" required="true" size="30" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>


                                                        <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <input id="firm" name="firm" placeholder="Firm" size="30" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="true" size="30" type="email" value="">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="true" size="30" type="tel" value="">
                                                        </div> <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <textarea cols="40" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required="true" rows="5">
</textarea>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="twelve col">
                                                            <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>

                                                <div id="contact_results"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>






 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
        var proceed = true;
        $("#contactform input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });
        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
            post_data = {
                'user_name'     : $('input[name=user_name]').val(), 
                'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
                'phone'         : $('input[name=phone]').val(), 
                'firm'          : $('input[name=firm]').val(), 
                'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
            };
            $.post('emal.php', post_data, function(response){  
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $("#contactform  input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                    $("#contactform").slideUp(); //hide form after success
                }
                $("#contactform #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
    $("#contactform  input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
```

**And the php side:**

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "info@denverbarr.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone          = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $firm           = filter_var($_POST["firm"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($use_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : ". $phone_number ;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => .$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

I'm going to assume the issue is here:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
        var proceed = true;
        $("#contactform input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });
```

Because Its the highlighting that is tripping out. It should be highlighting the Name, email, phone, and message boxes

Comment: This is an awful lot of code. Could you point out exactly which bit of it isn't working as expected, and explain what it's doing and what you *want* it to be doing?

Comment: `if(strlen($use_name)<4)` should be `if(strlen($user_name)<4)`

Comment: Updated the response @oxguy3

Comment: @oxguy3 If you check the link http://denverbarr.com You can see that the form isn't highlight entirely for some reason & for some reason it no longer wants to actually submit, whether that is related to the validation I don't know however.

Answer (score 1):

**Css Padding issue**

You have `css` code mistake for placeholder. You have missed `line-height`. You have to add `line-hight:20px;` in `#contact input, select` **class**. This class is in `main.css` file on near about 842 line.

**Validation issue**

On `$("#submit_btn").click` if you alert value of `user_name` text box. It gives 'Name' value. So that your validation getting `true`.
Try to add bellow in your `$("#submit_btn").click` and check :

```
alert($('#user_name').val())
```

OR for all input alert

```
alert($(this).val())
```

Comment: That fixed the padding issue thanks! Any ideas for the validation?

Comment: So I did that and your right its using the placeholder as a value.

Comment: Do you know how to stop it from taking the placeholder value?

Comment: i think that issue because of placeholder.js

Comment: ?                     
What do you mean

Answer (score 0):

You could start by fixing those errors :

(Sorry, can't post screenshot)

Uncaugh TypeError : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null placeholder.js:70

Uncaught SyntaxError : missing ) after argument list main.js:18

Comment: Fixed. Still throwing some problems